# Inserting rows for new table covering combinations of ID columns from TableA and TableB

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There are two existing tables, and I want to populate a new table (lets call that MiddleTable) with the combination of the ID columns from the existing tables.  Here are my table structures (over simplified), not that the IntField is important as on the insert I want this to be a specific value which can then change in a way unrelated to this problem.

**Table A**:

```
ID, Other columns
```

**Table B**:

```
ID, Other columns
```

**MiddleTable**

```
TableA_ID, TableB_ID, IntField, Other columns ....
```

My solution is like this, is there a simpler way or one without some important drawbacks?

```
INSERT INTO MiddleTable (TableA_ID, IntField, TableB_ID) 
  SELECT 
      X.TabAID, 0, X.TabBID 
  FROM 
      (SELECT 
           TableA.ID AS TabA_ID, TableB.ID AS TabB_ID 
       FROM 
           TableA, TableB
       EXCEPT 
       SELECT 
           TableA_ID, TableB_ID  
       FROM 
           MiddleTable) X
```

Comment: what do you mean by *without some important drawbacks*?

Comment: I guess I am wondering if the solution I stumbled upon has some problems that I might not encounter until the tables get much bigger?

Comment: But why you don't use `View` for this purpose? With your solution, you need to `truncate` or `delete` all record when `TableA` or `TableB` updated (if you have _other columns_ in your middle table which you haven't listed in your SQL but in table structure)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be equivalent and for SQL Server the more efficient way. That is if you have an INDEX in MiddleTable with `ID_A, ID_B` columns for fast lookup.

It also uses explicit `CROSS JOIN` instead of the implicit cross join by `FROM TableA, TableB`. As @marc_s already pointed out, the implicit syntax is old-school, deprecated and might be removed in future version of SQL Server.

---

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA(ID INT, Other NVARCHAR(128));
CREATE TABLE #TableB(ID INT, Other NVARCHAR(128));
CREATE TABLE #Middle(ID_A INT, ID_B INT, intfield INT, Other NVARCHAR(128));
ALTER TABLE -- index for fast lookup
    #Middle
ADD CONSTRAINT 
    PK_middle PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID_A,ID_B);

INSERT INTO #Middle(ID_A,ID_B,intfield)
SELECT
    A.ID,B.ID,0
FROM
    #TableA AS A
    CROSS JOIN #TableB AS B
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM #Middle AS m
        WHERE m.ID_A=A.ID AND m.ID_B=B.ID
    );
```

---

The `NOT EXISTS` condition will do a *left anti-semi join* to peek for existing rows so that these rows won't be inserted again. For SQL Server that is usually the more efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO Main_Table(TabA_ID,TabB_ID)
SELECT Table_A.ID,Table_B.ID FROM Table_A CROSS JOIN Table_B 
EXCEPT 
SELECT TabA_ID,TabB_ID FROM Main_Table
```